# How to force a column to only allow number in this fashion: 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 and so on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a **Star model** model and included `total_stars` and `average_stars` columns to the **Post** model:

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "average_stars", default: 0, null: false
    t.integer  "total_stars",   default: 0, null: false
  end
```

> def calculate_total_stars
>       if [Post].include?(starable.class)
>         self.starable.update_column(:total_stars, starable.total_stars + self.number)
>       end   end
>
> def calculate_average_stars
>       if [Post].include?(starable.class)
>         self.starable.update_column(:average_stars, starable.total_stars / starable.stars.count)
>       end   end

So now the problem is if the `average_stars` is `3.6` the end result is just `3`. I'm not very sure what kind of calculating or approximation is suitable for a five star rating system. But I would like it to go in the following fashion: 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5...

Any suggestion of how to modify the `average_stars` column to achieve that result?

Comment: You want to store 1.5,2.5 but the column is defined as integer. First change the data type of average_stars column

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring your average column as an integer declare it as a float (or decimal):

```
t.float  "average_stars", default: 0, null: false
```

Then when you're doing your calculation do:

```
def calculate_average_stars
  if [Post].include?(starable.class)
    self.starable.update_column(:average_stars, starable.total_stars.to_f / starable.stars.count)
  end
end
```

Which will give you a decimal value instead of a rounded/truncated integer. The `.to_f` is the important part there.

If you *want* it to be rounded or only have a fixed number of decimal points either use a Decimal column in your migration (which takes a :limit) or do some mathy stuff:

```
((starable.total_stars.to_f / starable.stars.count) * 100).round / 100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def calculate_average_stars
  if starable.is_a?(Post) 
    exact_average = starable.total_stars.to_f / starable.stars.count
    rounded_average = exact_average - (exact_average % 0.5)
    starable.update_column(:average_stars, rounded_average) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Modding by a decimal is pretty clever but you'll occasionally get weird floating-point precision and it'll look like 4.5000000000000002. I think it's better to round and then truncate it at a "reasonable" length.I couldn't really tell if the questioner really wanted it to round to the nearest half-star. If he did than your answer (in combination with the float-column) is closer to correct. Just do the mod and then make sure it's truncated to the correct decimal position (val * 10 / 10.0).